# Check if number is unique and then add it to an array. Help to find bug

Tags: c#, arrays, debugging

I am doing an app that uses Random() class and the method that fills the numbers in the array has a bug. It still adds the same values in the array. It is supposed to check if the random generated value is already in the array and if it is not in there to add it. Else it should leave the loop and generate another integer.

Code:

```
    /*
     * Method to fill in the array with numbers
     */
    public void FillArrayWithRandomNumbers()
    {

        bool unique = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < NrOfWantedNumbers; i++)
        {
            _randomNumber = rndm.Next(1, MaxValue) + 1;
            while (unique == false)
            {
                foreach (var item in storeLottoNum)
                {
                    if (item == _randomNumber)
                        unique = false;
                    else
                    {
                        unique = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (unique)
                storeLottoNum[storeNextIndex] = _randomNumber;
                ++storeNextIndex;
                unique = false;
        }  
    }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: What is the error?  It's just adding it over and over, and not producing an error?

Comment: It is adding the same value twice from time to time.

Comment: you need to exit the inner foreach loop once you find a match

Comment: Looking at the reference posted, you want to check the method "contains"

Comment: A kitten dies whenever you do a boolean check like `if (unique == true)`. Please, think of the kittens and just do `if (unique)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that :

- storeLottoNum is type int[];
- storeLottoNum has size = NrOfWantedNumbers
- storeNextIndex is initialized with 0

EDIT: Added comments to the code

then try:

```
  /*
 * Method to fill in the array with numbers
 */
public void FillArrayWithRandomNumbers()
{

     for (int i = 0; i < NrOfWantedNumbers; i++)  // for each number you want
    {
        do
        {
            unique = true;                                     // Assume new value is unique
            _randomNumber = rndm.Next(1, MaxValue) + 1;        // get the random number
            for (int item = 0; item < storeNextIndex; item++)  // Check each element with a value in your array
            {
                if (storeLottoNum[item] == _randomNumber)      // if the value is the same
                {
                    unique = false;       // It is not unique
                    break;                // break the loop, we don't care about the other values
                }
            }
        } while (unique == false);        // if it was not unique, try again

        storeLottoNum[storeNextIndex++] = _randomNumber;   // with unique value, save in the array and increment the 'storeNextIndex'
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code probably would work if you had added braces. You indented the code under your `if` statement, but didn't add any braces. This isn't Python.

```
if (unique == true) // By the way, can be shortened to if (unique)
{ // <-- You were missing this
    storeLottoNum[storeNextIndex] = _randomNumber;
    ++storeNextIndex;
    unique = false;
} // <-- You were missing this too
```

An easier way to do this though:

```
unique = !storeLottoNum.Contains(item)
```

That one line can complete eliminate your `while` loop and everything in it. This will set your `unique` variable automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the default characteristics of a [Dictionary<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) or [HashSet<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

These type of collections do not allow duplicate keys by default. When one is encountered in a dictionary, an exception is thrown. When one is encountered in a hashset, the duplicate is simply discarded. By wrapping the process of adding a KeyValuePair to a dictionary collection type, in a try/catch block and simply absorbing the exception when it's thrown, you can very easily build a list of random unique values. See the example below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LottoSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();

            // Dictionary to store list of random numbers
            Dictionary<int, bool> _lottoNumbers = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

            // Total amount of numbers
            int count = 50;

            while (count > 0)
            {
                // Attempt to add a new random number into the Dictionary of lotto numbers and reduce count by 1
                try
                {
                    _lottoNumbers.Add(random.Next(1, 100), true);
                    count--;
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Dictionaries and HashSets don't allow duplicate keys by default.
                    // When an attempt to add a duplicate to a dictionary is encountered, an exception is thrown.
                    // We simply ignore it. Because we still want X number of random numbers,
                    // we don't bother reducing the counter unless it succeeds.
                }
            }

            // Print the result
            foreach (var num in _lottoNumbers)
                Console.WriteLine(num);

            // Prevent the console window from closing
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the solution using a HashSet<>. This eliminates the need of having to use a Try/Catch block altogether. (since it is typically considered to be bad practice in a professional setting):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LottoSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random _random = new Random();

            // HashSet to store list of random numbers
            // When an attempt to add a duplicate is
            // encountered. They simply ignore the attempt silently.
            HashSet<int> _lottoNumbers = new HashSet<int>();

            // Total amount of numbers
            int _count = 50;
            int _randomNumber = -1;

            while (_count > 0)
            {
                // Get a random number
                _randomNumber = _random.Next(1, 100);
                _lottoNumbers.Add(_randomNumber); 
                _count--;
            }

            // Print the result
            foreach (var num in _lottoNumbers)
                Console.WriteLine(num);

            // Prevent the console window from closing
            Console.ReadLine();        
        }
    }
}
```

I know, I got a little carried away. Here is a more object oriented solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LottoSample
{
    class Program
    {
        const int QTY = 10;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // A lotto numbers object which is initialized with the total amount of random numbers.
            var _lottoNumbers = new LottoNumbers(QTY);

            Random _random = new Random();

            int _count = QTY;       // Iterator
            int _randomNumber = -1; // Stores the random number

            // As long as there is still slots available, add a new random number
            while (_count > 0)
            { 
                // Get a random number
                _randomNumber = _random.Next(1, 100);

                // Attempt to add the number to the lotto numbers
                if (_lottoNumbers.Add(_randomNumber) == true)
                {
                    // It was successful, reduce the count by 1
                    _count--;
                }
                // Otherwise, try again until a unique value is found.
            }

            // Display the result
            Console.WriteLine(_lottoNumbers.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class LottoNumbers
        {
            private HashSet<int> _numbers;
            private int _total;

            public LottoNumbers()
            {
                this._numbers = new HashSet<int>();
            }

            public LottoNumbers(int total)
                : this()
            {
                _total = total;
            }

            public bool Add(int number)
            {
                // Check to see if the count of numbers is greater than the limit
                // Throw an exception if so.
                if (this.Count() >= _total)
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

                // Check to see if the number already exists and return true if so.
                if (this._numbers.Contains(number))
                    return false;

                // Add the number otherwise and return true.
                this._numbers.Add(number);
                return true;
            }

            // Overriden ToString() that displays a formatted list of numbers 
            public override string ToString()
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var n in _numbers)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0}", n);

                    // If the number isn't the last in the list, append a comma
                    if (n != _numbers.Last())
                    {
                        sb.Append(",");
                    }
                }

                return sb.ToString();
            }

            // Get the count of numbers
            private int Count()
            {
                return this._numbers.Count();
            }
        }
    }
}
```